# How to open a ".sb" file?

Tags: 14.04, bash, files, executable

I downloaded a game in .sb format that is partition is Ubuntu but even with the terminal I can not seem to open it. Here's what it said:

```
fruity@xXxFruityxXx:~/Downloads$ /home/fruity/Téléchargements/wtf_2.sb 
bash: /home/fruity/Téléchargements/wtf_2.sb: can not execute binary file: Format error exec ()
```

How do I open this file?

This is what [Google translator](https://goo.gl/E9Yqnb) says.

Comment: `.sb` can indicate a couple of various formats..whats the output of `file /home/fruity/Téléchargements/wtf_2.sb ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a game made with Scratch (https://scratch.mit.edu/). But it seems to be one of the older (offline) version of Scratch.
You can install Scratch with `sudo apt-get install scratch` or by searching for "Scratch" in the Software Manager